# How to deal with character with accents in Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, encoding, pymongo

I am processing a database that contains spanish characters as á, é, í, ñ, etc...
Importing them worked fine, and using the command line shows that characters are correctly encoded in the database:

```
> use climaescolar
switched to db climaescolar
> db.preguntas.findOne()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("55a912e69b874f7cc9afa322"),
        "Indice" : "A-1",
        "Pregunta" : "Eres:",
        "Tipologia" : "Única respuesta",
        "Respuestas posibles" : 2,
        "Respuestas maximas" : 1,
        "Respuesta" : "1.Hombre-2.Mujer",
        "Adicionales" : "95.Respuesta anulada-96.No Responde-97.Marca más de una respuesta-98.Opciones Incompatibles/incompletas-99.En blanco"
}
```

(Note that "Ú" and "á" are displayed correctly)

However, when I process the answers using Pymongo, characters appear in unicode format:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient("127.0.0.1", 27017)
db = client["climaescolar"]
col = db.preguntas
print(col.find_one())
```

returns:

```
{u'Respuesta': u'1.Hombre-2.Mujer', u'Respuestas posibles': 2, u'Pregunta': u'Eres:', u'Respuestas maximas': 1, u'Tipologia': u'\xdanica respuesta', u'\ufeffIndice': u'A-1', u'Adicionales': u'95.Respuesta anulada-96.No Responde-97.Marca m\xe1s de una respuesta-98.Opciones Incompatibles/incompletas-99.En blanco', u'_id': ObjectId('55a912e69b874f7cc9afa322')}
```

(note that "Única respuesta" appears as "\xdanica respuesta" )

I read the note on unicode format strings in the [docs](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html), but have not been able to solve it. Any suggestions?

Comment: In case that someone is trying to process a database with spanish characters I would also add that I had to save the tsv file with UTF-8 encoding (NOT UTF-8 with BOM, because it will introduce an `\ufeff`character at the beggining of the file).

Answer (score 0):

I think its a feature of the print function, not pymongo.

If you run the following:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient("127.0.0.1", 27017)
db = client["climaescolar"]
col = db.preguntas
for key, value in col.find_one().iteritems():
    print(u'{0}: {1}'.format(key, value))
```

You will get

```
Indice:A-1
Respuesta:1.Hombre-2.Mujer
Respuestas posibles:2.0
Pregunta:Eres:
Respuestas maximas:1.0
Tipologia:Única respuesta
Adicionales:95.Respuesta anulada-96.No Responde-97.Marca más de una respuesta-98.Opciones Incompatibles/incompletas-99.En blanco
_id:55a9272ef7ba789df8b5c858
```

Comment: I got: `Respuesta: 1.Hombre-2.Mujer
Respuestas posibles: 2
Pregunta: Eres:
Respuestas maximas: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mongoExample.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(u'{0}: {1}'.format(key, value))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xda' in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)`